# Latest entries in SQL table are not showing when executing the script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have database. Everyday third party software insert parameters to the SQL tables, We want to see latest updated data in SQL, today what ever entered into SQL we want to see

1) When I executed below script, it showing updated 5000 tags except some tags which start with %HO%, these tags are updated along with other tags at the same time

```
Select  top 5000 [T_idx]  ,[T_TAG]   ,[T_Date] from [house].[dbo].[total]
```

2) When I execute below particularly for %HO% tags all are listing

```
Select * from [house].[dbo].[total] where T_TAG like '%HO%' order by T_Date DESC
```

Can any one suggest me one script where i can see all tags with respect to the date and time as per my wish

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `order by` statement to your first query:

```
Select top 5000 [T_idx], [T_TAG], [T_Date]
from [house].[dbo].[total]
order by T_Date desc;
```

Without the `order by`, you are getting arbitrary rows from the table.  If you want to see *all* the tags from all times, remove the `top 5000`:

```
Select [T_idx], [T_TAG], [T_Date]
from [house].[dbo].[total]
order by T_Date desc;
```